# Making g++ point this error/Warning out

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I currently had a statement like this

```
std::string student::returnData()
{
   // return "This is return type" ;
    std::cout << "Hello World";
}
```

However when I built the C++ project as such

```
entry: main.o student.o
       g++ -W -Wall -Werror -o $@ main.o student.o

main.o: 
    g++ -W -Wall -Werror -c main.cpp

clean:
      rm -rf *.o entry
```

I wasnt given a warning/error and  when this method executed the output started going crazy 
Any suggestions on what I could do so I could get warned with silly mistakes like these

Comment: Did you redirect your errors to some files while making ?

Comment: Do you have a rule for `student.o`, or are you using the implicit rule?

Comment: No i dont have a rule for student.o

Comment: So, by default, you don't get any warnings. Add a rule, or change the implicit rules by setting `CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Werror`. You should consider adding `Wextra` to the list of flags.

Comment: Thanks that did it. Could you put that down as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc` will emit an error with flags `-Wall -Werror`. The problem is that you don't have a rule for target `student.o`, and the implicit rules do not use any warning flags. The simplest approach might be to set the warning flags globally, and let the implicit rules do their thing. This can be achieved by using the `CXXFLAGS` variable (or `CFLAGS` for C code):

```
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Werror
```

This will take care of `student.o` and any `.o` that doesn't have an explicit rule. Note that this rule makes `student.o` implicitly dependent on `student.cpp`, student.cc`or student.C`. You can add dependencies without modifying the recipe like this:

```
student.o: student.h  # student.o now depends on student.h too
```

This would result in an error of the form

> error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]

I suggest adding the `Wextra` warning flag.